# Vim: paste after last space?

Tags: vim

I often want to paste some text after the last space in line. If I have

```
sometext <cursor>
```

and press Ctr+O, P, I got

```
sometext<pasted_text>
```

instead

```
sometext <pasted_text>
```

How do I achieve the latter in vim?

Comment: Why are you using ctrl-o there? That goes to a previous cursor position, right? It looks like you have your cursor where you want it already.

Comment: No, C-o puts you in normal mode for one command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you using (upper-case) `P`? That inserts text before the current cursor position. Lower-case `p` puts it after.

Answer (score 6):

If your line is

```
sometext$
```

where **$** is the end of the line,
then try `o<Esc>pkJ` to get

```
sometext pastedtext$
```

If your line is

```
sometext $
```

then just do `$p` to get

```
sometext pastedtext$
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach I take, paste it on the next line, then move up and `shift+j` it. Alternatively, you could do `shift+a` then `esc` then `p`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just go

```
<c-r><register key>  
eg <c-r>0  for last yank
<c-r>" for last deleted text
```

Assuming your cursor is where you want it to be and you're in insert mode.

This may be more fluid.

note  also works on the : command line

Answer (score 1):

You should type (without comma)
$, p

Answer (score 0):

put this in your .vimrc

```
nnoremap <leader>p <esc>pkJ
```

I have my leader set to ,

```
let mapleader = ","
```

now you can just do `,p`